# UISearchBar that Searches Entire UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a tableview that filters based on a search bar. This works well as long as the search begins with the same characters as the cell text.

I would like to be able to search any part of the cell text, even in the middle. For example. If the cell text is "Jon Bon Jovi" I would like it to still come up if the user types "Bon Jovi" or even just "Jovi" into the search bar.

My current code is below:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in listItems)
{

    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [[item objectForKey:@"type"]  
    isEqualToString:scope] || scope == nil)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [[item objectForKey:@"name"] 
        compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) 
        range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [filteredListItems addObject:item];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `-compare:options:range:` (which just sorts your search string relative to your item's name), consider looking at [`-rangeOfString:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_options_) - that will actually search the entire item name for your search string. You would replace the inner body of your `if` statement with something like:

```
NSStringCompareOptions opts = (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch);
NSRange resultRange = [[item objectForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:searchText
                                                         options:opts];
if (resultRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    [filteredListItems addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: Hi @tim, I just opened a related question about ignoring special characters (apostrophes, dashes, etc) when searching the tableview cells. There link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419955/uisearchbar-that-ignores-special-characters-when-searching-uitableview-cell. If you have any ideas It would be awesome :). Thanks again for your help on this post though!